# How to filter an array and get the values by recent month in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array:

```js
var array = [{
    "date": "2022-09-08T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.70",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-08-24T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.20",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-08-02T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "0.03",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-04-15T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.20",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-04-10T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.32",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-03-10T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.50",
  }
]
```

I am trying to filter the array by passing a selectedMonth value as follows:

```js
public filterByMonth(
  rates: Row[],
  selectedMonth: Date
): Row[] {
  return rates ? .filter(
    (d) =>
    d.date ? .getMonth() === selectedMonth? .getMonth() &&
    d.date ? .getFullYear() === selectedMonth? .getFullYear()
  );
}
```

The above snippet gives me the result I need. But, if the selected month doesn't have any value the array should return the value in the array that is less than selectedMonth.

Example:
If selected month is August(08): the result is as follows:

```
array = [{
    "date": "2022-08-24T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.20",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-08-02T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "0.03",
  }]
```

If the selected month is July, I get an empty array. But, I want it to find values less than the selected month. In this case, it is April.

**Expected Result:**

```
array = [{
    "date": "2022-04-15T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.20",
  },
  {
    "date": "2022-04-10T04:00:00.000Z",
    "value": "1.32",
  }]
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: It's not clear what is the required result is. Do you need the values of selected month only and if there's none get those less than that month? If so, how many of those values less that month should be returned?

Comment: @FadiHania I just need the latest month values which are less than the selected month. If I select July in the above array I just need April result not the march.

Comment: I think it will be easier to use nested for statements to check for months starting by selected month then next months one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a recursive call by calling the same **filterByMonth** function with **month - 1** until you find a value. Also add a termination condition for the year. Ex:- 2020

sample pseudo code for the function

```
public filterByMonth(
  rates: Row[],
  selectedMonth: Date
): Row[] {

  // termination condition 
      // termination condition is year 2020
    if(selectedMonth.getFullYear() === 2020){
      return [];
    }

  const filteredRates =  rates ? .filter(
    (d) =>
    d.date ? .getMonth() === selectedMonth? .getMonth() &&
    d.date ? .getFullYear() === selectedMonth? .getFullYear()
  );

  if(filteredRates.length === 0){

      let month = selectedMonth.getMonth();
      let year = selectedMonth.getMonth();
      if(month === 0){
        month = 11;
        year = year - 1;
      } else {
        month = month - 1
      }
      return this.filterByMonth(rates, new Date(selectedMonth.getFullYear(), selectedMonth.getMonth() - 1));
    } else {
      return filteredRates;
    }
  }
}
```

Also find the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-psknhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,lib.es5.d.ts) here